# How to capture signature in Salesforce1 (Mobile App)

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning

I want to capture digital signature using mobile devices in Salesforce1 (Mobile App).

I want to store my signature in the system so that I have an option to store my signature electronically in Salesforce1 (Salesforce Mobile App).

Answer (score 0):

There is an AppExchange App which does this [Signature Capture App](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5XOEAY)

This is not compatible with Locker Service in Lightning.

> Signature Capture is a pure HTML5 native Lightning Component to allow users to draw a signature on a web page associated with a Salesforce record.
>
> This process is repeated until the user is happy the image is an
>   accurate representation of their signature, at which point they click
>   a button to save to Salesforce.